# Let $(A; ≼)$ be any poset. Prove that the relation $≺ := ≼ ∩ ≠$ on A is transitive.

Tags: abstract-algebra, discrete-mathematics

How can i prove this ?
Let $(A; ≼)$ be any poset. Prove that the relation $≺ := ≼ ∩ ≠$ on A is transitive.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $a, b, c \in A$ be such that $a ≺ b$ and $b ≺ c$. By the definition of $≺$, this means that$ (1) a ≼ b$, $(2) a \neq b$, $(3) b ≼ c$, and $(4) b \neq c$. From (1) and (3), and the transitivity of $≼$, it follows that $a ≼ c$. It remains to show that $a \neq $c. Assume towards a contradiction that $a = c$. This, together with (1), implies that c ≼ b. But this, together with (3) and the antisymmetry of $≼$, implies that $ b = c$, which is a contradiction to (4).
Overall, we showed that for any $a, b, c ∈ A$, such that $a ≺ b$ and $b ≺ c$, we have $a ≼ c$ and $a \neq c$. This, by the definition of$ ≺$, means that a  $≺ c$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $a<b$ and $b<c$.

Then $a\leq b$ and $b\leq c$ so that the transitivity of $\leq$ guarantees that $a\leq c$.

It remains to prove that $a\neq c$.

If $a=c$ then we have $a\leq b$ and $b\leq a$, hence $a=b$ on base of antisymmetry.

This however contradicts that $a<b$.